# Android Room cannot recognize TypeConverer for List

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

Here's my Entity:

```
@Entity(tableName = "commits")
data class Commit(
        @PrimaryKey
        @ColumnInfo(name = "hash")
        val hash: String,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "changes", typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.BLOB)
        var changes: List<DbChange>
)
```

And here's the converters:

```
class Converters {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        @TypeConverter
        fun changesToByteArray(changes: List<DbChange>): ByteArray {
            ...
        }

        @JvmStatic
        @TypeConverter
        fun byteArrayToChanges(bytes: ByteArray): List<DbChange> {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

And I've already added Converters class to the annotations:

```
@Database(entities = [Commit::class], version = 1)
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
abstract class AppRoomDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    ...
}
```

But the compiler still complains:

```
e: /home/perqin/workspaces/cent-budget/cent-budget/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/eaDebug/com/perqin/centbudget/data/sync/commit/Commit.java:20: error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it.
    private java.util.List<? extends com.perqin.centbudget.data.sync.changes.DbChange> changes;
```

How to solve this issue? I have no ideas at all...

Comment: You just need to visit this blog: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/room-data-storage-for-everyone/

Comment: @pRaNaY No I don't want the DbChange to be an Entity. Actually DbChange is an interface and I need to serialize and deserialize it manually according to implementation.

Comment: Have you tried `@Ignore` to avoid compiler error which you are getting?
`@Ignore var changes: List<DbChange>`

Comment: @pRaNaY `@Ignore` may not be what I want, because I do need to store serialized `changes` into database.

Comment: I'm curious, what happens if you change `List` to `MutableList` ?

Answer (score 3):

This is actually Kotlin's fault rather than Room's.
As you can see in your error message you get `List<? extends DbChange>` instead of `List<DbChange>` for `changes` field and thus Room tried to find `TypeConverters` for `byte[] -> List<? extends DbChange>` and `List<? extends DbChange> -> byte[]`, but fails to do so.

That's because `changesToByteArray` method argument type is generated as `List<? extends DbChange>`, **but** type of `byteArrayToChanges` method is still `List<DbChange>` and thus you get a compilation error.

I would recommend [this](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-suppress-wildcards/index.html) article if you want read more.

**Solution 1:**
Use [`@JvmSuppressWildcards`](http://adavis.info/2017/08/jvmsuppresswildcards-biggest-annoyance-kotlin.html)
Annotate `Commit` class so that type without wildcards will be generated for `changes` field and it's setter:

```
@Entity(tableName = "commits")
@JvmSuppressWildcards
data class Commit(
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "hash")
    val hash: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "changes", typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.BLOB)
    var changes: List<DbChange>
)
```

Annotate `List`'s type for same reason:

```
class Converters {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        @TypeConverter
        fun changesToByteArray(changes: List<@JvmSuppressWildcards DbChange>): ByteArray {
            ...
        }

        @JvmStatic
        @TypeConverter
        fun byteArrayToChanges(bytes: ByteArray): List<DbChange> {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

**Solution 2:**
Create wrapper class for your list like:

```
data class DbChanges(val list: List<DbChange>)
```

and then update `Commit` class:

```
@Entity(tableName = "commits")
data class Commit(
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "hash")
    val hash: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "changes", typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.BLOB)
    var changes: DbChanges
)
```

and write new `TypeConverters`:

```
class Converters {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        @TypeConverter
        fun changesToByteArray(changes: DbChanges): ByteArray {
            ...
        }

        @JvmStatic
        @TypeConverter
        fun byteArrayToChanges(bytes: ByteArray): DbChanges {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```